# Elements added to DOM tree via `appendChild`don't show up in IE6/7 (also `onclick` events not firing)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, dom, html-table

Consider the following JavaScript code, meant to create an 8x8 table inside of a container div with `id="c"`:

```
//first, two shortcut functions
function $id(a){return(a&&a.nodeType)?a:document.getElementById(a);}
function $cr8(a){return document.createElement(a);}

//now the meat    
var ct = $id('c'),
    t = $cr8('table'),
    tr, td,
    row = 8, cols = 8,
    tdclkfn = function () { alert('row: '+this.i+' col: '+this.j); }

for(var i=0;i<row;i++) {
    tr = $cr8('tr');
    for(var j=0;j<cols;j++) {
        td = $cr8('td');
        td.i = i;
        td.j = j;
        td.onclick = tdclkfn;
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    t.appendChild(tr);
}
ct.appendChild(t);
```

This works as expected in Firefox, Chrome, and IE8. Not so much in IE6/IE7. As you can see in [this live example](http://jsfiddle.net/PKfaF/), it's as if the table markup isn't there.

If you poke around under the hood using either Firebug Lite or the IE Developer Toolbar, you can discover that the DOM elements are actually there, they're just not displayed for some reason. Anybody know why?

I decided to see what would happen if I added `ct.innerHTML += '<div/>'` to the tail end of the above JavaScript. Presto, it shows up (see [this updated live example](http://jsfiddle.net/75NhM/)). Why does this fix the problem?

Additionally, the function I've attached to the `onclick` event handler for each `<td>`? Apparently it doesn't fire at all. It's attached, you can trigger it by a manual call, but clicking on the cell? Nope, not in IE6/7. Why?

I'm aware I can get around this by using a nicely-behaved JS/DOM framework, but I'd really be curious to find out what's going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table` elements can't directly contain `tr` elements; IE and other browsers are happy to handle it for you when parsing markup (inserting the `tbody` automatically; see below), but apparently IE is more finicky when you're manipulating the DOM directly.

If you put a `tbody` in there, IE6 and IE7 are happy (the boxes show up, the click handlers work):

```
var ct = $id('c'),
    t = $cr8('table'),
    tbody = $cr8('tbody'),
    tr, td,
    row = 8, cols = 8,
    tdclkfn = function () {
        alert('row: '+this.i+' col: '+this.j);
    }

for(var i=0;i<row;i++) {
    tr = $cr8('tr');
    for(var j=0;j<cols;j++) {
        td = $cr8('td');
        td.i = i;
        td.j = j;
        td.onclick = tdclkfn;
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
t.appendChild(tbody);
ct.appendChild(t);
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/amosi4) (on jsbin.com; I don't seem to have much luck with IE6 and IE7 and jsfiddle.net). Your original code [here](http://jsbin.com/amosi4/2) for comparison on the same site.

Regarding inserting the `tbody` for you automatically, you can see that in action:

HTML:

```
<table id='theTable'><tr><td>Test</td></tr></table>
```

(Note no `tbody`.)

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var elm, markup;

  elm = document.getElementById('theTable');
  markup = ["<ol>"];
  walk(elm);
  markup.push("</ol>");
  display(markup.join(""));

  function walk(node) {
    var child;

    markup.push("<li>");
    markup.push(node.nodeName);
    if (node.nodeType === 1 ||
        node.nodeType === 9 ||
        node.nodeType === 11) {
      markup.push("<ol>");
      for (child = node.firstChild;
           child;
           child = child.nextSibling) {
        walk(child);
      }
      markup.push("</ol>");
    }
    markup.push("</li>");
  }

  function display(markup) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = markup;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
};
```

Output:

1. TABLE

   1. TBODY

      1. TR

         1. TD

            1. #text

Note the `tbody` in there.

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ivaka4)

Comment: Kinda long winded TJ, but you got there in the end. :-) The bottom line is when building a table using DOM, IE requires a TBODY element to be added explicitly, other browsers will add it by default.

Comment: @RobG: LOL Well, I think the opening paragraph was brief and to the point. I just went with an example or two... (Also, I'd forgotten exactly what happens with `tbody` because it's been so long since I didn't include them explicitly; so I double-checked...)

Comment: Great answer. Also implicitly explains why the `ct.innerHTML +=` makes things visible... IE6/7 are tolerant of loose markup (which we're essentially directly inserting here).

Comment: @Weston C: Ah, yes, I didn't actually mention that, did I? But you were on it. :-) Glad that helped,